Why does my iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2014), running macOS Big Sur 11.6, not boot from external USB drive with an older macOS?
Why does my iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2014), running macOS Big Sur 11.6, not boot from external USB drive with an older macOS?
I've tried everything without luck.
All the external drives show up as eligible options in “System Preferences > Startup Disk,” but on startup it keeps reverting to my normal startup disk.
Holding down Option at restart does not show me any alternate startup disks. I've tried various external drive bays.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Which older macOS?

OS X Yosemite Mac OS X 10.10
Complete specs here —
https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i5-3.5-27-inch-aluminum-retina-5k-late-2014-specs.html
Thanks for your response

How did you install Yosemite on the external drive?  What version of Yosemite? May need to be at least 10.10.2

It's 10.10.11. I installed it from an official complete installer downloaded from apple.

OS X 10.10.11 does not exist.

That was a typo. It's 10.10.5.

Sounds like the Mac may have the firmware password set. Can you boot to macOS Internet Recovery by holding down Option-Shift-Command-R at startup? If so, open the Terminal application and post the output from sw_vers.

Thanks David, I'll try that. Would you be willing to explain what it means to "have the firmware password set" ? Is it some security measure that I'm unaware of? Thanks again.

I was reading this similar question. User Linc Davis posted a comment regarding a password being set. I thought maybe you have a similar problem. See this Apple website.

OS X Yosemite is too old when comparing to the current macOS Big Sur. Not to mention APFS is required for booting volume since High Sierra.
You'd better to run a newer macOS (such as High Sierra) from external drive or downgrade the current macOS to an old version like El Capitan in order to run OS X Yosemite from external drive.
By the way, you should use the current machine to install macOS on an external drive and run from it for maximum compability.

Thank you Keagan! Now I have some idea what's next.

I am not sure I would accept the idea that installing El Capitan would somehow make the firmware recognize a Yosemite installation on an external drive.
